# reactjs dispatch promise continuously after specific time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-promise

In my react component I am calling an action in `ComponentDidMount()` like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
        const { actions } = this.props

        function save_project_continiously() {
            console.log("inside")
            actions.save_project().then(save_project_continiously)
        }

        save_project_continiously()
    }
```

Here I am calling an action continuously.. My actions is like:

```
export function save_project() {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {

        setTimeout(() => {
            return dispatch(manage_data()).then(response => {
                console.log("Hellooww world")
                return response
            })
        }, 3000)
    }
}
```

When I do this it gives me error saying `.then()` is not a function in `ComponentDidMount()` ..

If I do

```
export function save_project() {
        return (dispatch, getState) => {

            return dispatch(manage_data()).then(response => {
                console.log("Hellooww world")
                return response
            })
        }
    }
```

It is called continuously but I want it to be called continuously after specific time.

I tried this:

```
export function save_project() {
        return (dispatch, getState) => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    return dispatch(manage_data()).then(response => {
                        console.log("Hellooww world")
                        return response
                    })
                }, 3000)
            })
        }
    }
```

But it is only called once.. Does not give any error but it only calls once..

What I want is I want to call an actions continuosly after specific time after completing the action.

Here I want to call `save_project`  and after completing it I again want to call it after 3 seconds and go on continuously ..

How can I make it happen ??

Any suggestions ??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code, you're wrapping promise in promise, but what you actually want to do is execute this code again on successful promise resolve.

```
export function save_project() {
    // So this code does return callback, so it does not return promise
    // in your first example.
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        // Then this code returns promise, but it never gets resolved.
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                // Then you return promise from set timeout, but it
                // is doubtful as well
                return dispatch(manage_data()).then(response => {
                    console.log("Hellooww world")
                    return response
                })
            }, 3000)
        })
    }
}
```

What you really want to do is:

```
// Just return promise of dispatch instead of wrapping it in
// a callback.
export function save_project() {
    return dispatch(manage_data());
}

// Then use set timeout here
function save_project_continiously() {
    console.log("inside")
    actions.save_project().then(() => {
        setTimeout(save_project_continiously, 3000);
    });
}
```

Or if you really want a callback in `save_project`, you need to call it properly with proper args as in your example they're `undefined` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try `setInterval()`

```
export function save_project() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      dispatch(manage_data()).then(response => {
        resolve(response);
      }, error => {
        reject(response);
      })
    }, 3000)
  });
}
```

Comment: This will call on every 3 second. But my `manage` data might take 10 sec to execute.. What I want is `save_project` shoud be called after 3 seconds only if `manage_data` has successfully completed.. Will this work

Comment: Updated my answer. If this doesn't work, I'm sorry but your code is very confusing. It's not clear at all what `dispatch` or `manage_data()` do.